# How to change view size without calling requestLayout()

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-view, layoutparams

I'm developing a game which has a lot of views in a layout.

Each game loop (33ms) one of the views is changing it's size, so I do this on the LayoutParams variable applied on the View on each loop with the new size.

```
params.width = realWidth;
params.height = realHeight;
```

The problem is that the change is not reflected if I didn't call `view.requestLayout()` and that is a huge problem because requestLayout() is repaiting the parent layout and all its childrens, **slowing down the game**.

How can the size changes of a view be reflected without calling requestLayout?

Comment: You can try calling [`layout(int, int, int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#layout(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) on the view followed by `invalidate()`, but it's dirty solution because parent should be responsible for laying out the children, and it cannot be done without full layout pass since it's possible that view positions can be relative to each other. Instead I'd recommend looking into some kind of 2d framework because Views were not designed for that.

Comment: What Pawel said; the way the android layout system works is by making two _or more if needed_ passes. When a view changes its size, someone has to make sure the others are accommodated; there may be less or more space, etc. So views have to me re-measured, a layout pass mas occur, and children of ViewGroups updated, one by one... if your game depends upon fast graphics performance, then use OpenGL (or any of the libraries that abstract the complexity for you, like the well-known `LibGDX`).

Comment: @Pawel I'm trying it with layout but the view has a very rare behaviour, and when i add more views, they become invisible and appear on the left top corner for a millisecond